# Nested Live Apps

Tags: quip, liveapps

I'm working on a Live App right now... in a simple way, I want to create "tabs" inside of a Quip document. Each tab has its own RichTextBox that the user can edit, and clicking on a tab swaps the content out to its own RichTextBox.

This seems like a fairly straightforward bit, except for the fact that I would like the content boxes within each tab to behave just as a regular Quip document - including the ability to insert other Live Apps.

Is there a way to setup a RichTextBox such that it could contain nested LiveApps?

Answer (score 0):

No, Live Apps cannot be inserted inside other Live Apps.